# Creating Sub-Collection in Document from Flutter app

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a sub-collection in a document and set data to documents in the created sub-collection.

I have tried this but the program crashes every time I run this.

```
  await Firestore.instance
      .collection('/path')
      .document("documentPath")
      .collection('/subCollectionPath')
      .document()
      .setData({
    'TestData': "Data",
  }).then((onValue) {
    print('Created it in sub collection');
  }).catchError((e) {
    print('======Error======== ' + e);
  });
```

I have also looked online but I cannot find any documentation for it.

Any ideas?

When I try the above code, the app crashes with the following message

```
   flutter: EVENT StorageTaskEventType.success
   *** First throw call stack:
   (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111eb61bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111454735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Runner                              0x000000010ce707b1 -[FIRFirestore documentWithPath:] + 257
    3   Runner                              0x000000010d10662c getDocumentReference + 124
    4   Runner                              0x000000010d109879 -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 2665
    5   Flutter                             0x000000010e5b99a2 __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 115
    6   Flutter                             0x000000010e5d6616 _ZNK5shell21PlatformMessageRouter21HandlePlatformMessageEN3fml6RefPtrIN5blink15PlatformMessageEEE + 166
    7<…>
```

Lost connection to device.

Comment: Try - `Firestore.instance
        .collection('/path')
        .document("documentPath")
        .collection('/subCollectionPath').reference()
        .document()
        .setData({
      'TestData': "Data",
    }).then((onValue) {
      print('Created it in sub collection');
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('======Error======== ' + e);
    });`

Comment: That didn't work. The same thing happened. The app crashed.

Comment: I edited the question to add the message. See question above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
 final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
databaseReference.collection('main collection name').document( unique id).collection('string name').document().setData(); // your answer missing **.document()**  before setData
```

this is the right Syntex

Comment: can you please let me know how can I retrieve data after storing data in the above structure. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Figured out the problem. I was using the wrong syntax. The correct syntax is

```
    Firestore.instance.collection('path').document("documentPath").collection('subCollectionPath').setData({});
```

The key difference here is that the forward slashes have been removed from the paths name.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution, if you want to create a subcollection within a Firestore Transaction:

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) {
    tx.set(Firestore.instance.collection('path').document('documentPath')
        .collection('subCollectionPath').document(), {'TestData', 'Data'});
})
```

NOTE: You cannot create an empty subcollection, you must create the subcollection with at least one document. If you try to create the subcollection with the data field empty, Firestore will create an empty document.

Answer (score 1):

**For Fetching SubCollection Data, use this query**

```
var query  = await databaseReference.collection('Staffs').document("horlaz229@gmail.com"). collection('Wallet').getDocuments()
```